# TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined Fast2sms

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send sms using fast2sms in nodejs and I am facing some issues in it.

The error is like :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
at Object.sendMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\node_modules\fast-two-sms\index.js:37:27)

Here is my code:

```js
try {
  const type = 'phone'
  res.render('verify', {
    'type': type
  })
  console.log(phone)
  await fastTwoSms.sendMessage({
    authorization: process.env.API_KEY,
    message: `Your Otp is ${otp}`,
    number: [phone]
  })
} catch (error) {
  next(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error i checked the library

> (https://github.com/raxraj/fast-two-sms/blob/master/index.js)

at line 37.

```
let url = 'https://www.fast2sms.com/dev/bulk';
let nums = props.numbers.join(',');
```

It expects `numbers` as input key not `number`.

Just change number to numbers and it will work.

```
await fastTwoSms.sendMessage({
    authorization: process.env.API_KEY,
    message: `Your Otp is ${otp}`,
    numbers: [phone]
})
```